# Warnings in astropy.time in Python

Tags: python, warnings, astropy

I recently installed Astropy for Python so that I could work with times prior to Jan 1 1AD, but anytime I use it, it gives a warning which says

```
dubious year for UTC (before 1960.0 or 5 years beyond last known leap second) [astropy.time.core]
```

The program still works, but it prints that prior to printing what I want it too. It may print it several times, too, one for each time I use a time prior to 1960, apparently.

Is there a way to making these warnings go away, or a least ignore them so they don't show up?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the UTC time scale was only defined in 1960 so it doesn't make sense to represent an earlier time in UTC. You could try and use a different time scale, e.g.:

```
t = Time(..., scale='ut1')
```

See [here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/time/index.html) for a list of available scales, and make sure you understand what scale you are using.

The other option is to stick to UTC (which is technically not quite right) and suppress the warnings. For this, you can use the [standard way](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) of doing this in Python:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    ... (your code here)
```

Comment: I tried to use UT1 instead, but then it wouldn't run at all, giving me a error which said 'IndexError: (some) times are outside of range covered by IERS table.'